# Java Wrtie an isSubstring Method

Tags: java, string

I am stuck at solving this problem. Below is what I came up with most:

Question: Write the boolean method public static boolean isSubstring(String x, String y) that takes two Strings x and y as arguments and returns true if an only if String x is a substring of String y. String x is a substring of String y if and only if all characters in x appear consecutively in y. For this problem, the only String methods you may use are length( ) and charAt( ). If you use any other String methods, you will receive no credit for this problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter String 1:");
        String String1 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter String 2:");
        String String2 = input.nextLine();

        if(isSubstring(String1,String2)){
            System.out.println("True");
        } else {
            System.out.println("False");
        }
    }
    public static boolean isSubstring(String x, String y) {

        int count = 0, xIndex = 0, yIndex = 0;
        boolean sub = false;

        while(!sub && yIndex < y.length()){
         if(y.charAt(yIndex) == x.charAt(yIndex)){
            xIndex++;
            count++;
         } else {
            if(count == x.length()){
               sub = true;
            } 
         }
         yIndex++;
      }
      return sub;
    }
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: classes start with an upper case letter.

Comment: Start by writing down in words how you are going to solve the problem.

Comment: @Reis - what specific is the question? Does the posted code work, or is there an error, or puts out the wrong answer in some cases?  Please give us a specific question...

Comment: First step in solving this is to step through the code in your IDE debugger.

Comment: A
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
 at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
 at q15.isSubstring(q15.java:23)
 at q15.main(q15.java:11)

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

Comment: That is the error. I entered the question above the code. Specific question is exactly answer to the question that was given above. String x (for ex ABA) has to be looked searched into String y (for ex BABA). Return needs to be boolean true or false (in this case true since ABA exists consequently inside BABA)

Comment: Let's say `x=ABA` and `y=BABA` indeed.  So `x.length()=3` and `y.length()=4`.  Look at your loop, `while(!sub && yIndex < y.length()){
         if(y.charAt(yIndex) == x.charAt(yIndex)){ ...`During the last iteration, yIndex will be 3.  So `y.charAt(yIndex)` will work, but `x.charAt(yIndex)` obviously will not, because the 3 is out of range for the index of String x.  The index for a String with 3 characters can be [0, 1, 2].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This checks if s2 is a substring of s1.

```
public static boolean isSubstring(String s1, String s2){
    if(s1.length()<s2.length()) return false;
    if(s1.length()==s2.length()) return s1.equals(s2);
    for(int i=0;i<=s1.length()-s2.length();i++){
        if(s1.charAt(i)==s2.charAt(0)){
            int matchLength=1;
            for(int j=1;j<s2.length();j++){
                if(s1.charAt(i+j)!=s2.charAt(j)){
                    break;
                }
                matchLength++;
            }
            if(matchLength==s2.length()) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not guarding xIndex for overflow. Guess if substring y is placed at end of x it fails. Also mind the case where x is of smaller length than x, could just return false then as optimization if you keep lengths first in local vars at start of method

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Task_1_9 {
  public static boolean isSubstring(String s1, String s2){
      if (s1.length() != s2.length()) return false;
      int count = 0;
      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;
      String s3 = s2 + s2;
      while (j < s3.length() && count < s1.length()){
          if (s1.charAt(i) == s3.charAt(j)){
              count++;
              i++;
          } else {
              count = 0;
          }
          j++;
      }
      return count == s1.length() ? true : false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(isSubstring("waterbottle","erbottlewat"));
  }
}
```